# HTML5 - window.localStorage retrieve data

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently data into a local db as following:

```
    window.localStorage.setItem('QQIDVAL' + ID, JSON.stringify(this));
```

How do I go about then retrieving all of the data that is in the localstorage and looking for ones that start with "QQ"

Also how do I go about selecting which columns I want to retreive as JSON.stringify(this) has a lot of columns but I only need a subset of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `localStorage` is treated like an object and do something like this (iterating through the keys and checking their name):

```
​for(dataObj in localStorage) {
    if(dataObj.charAt(0) == Q && dataObj.charAt(1) == Q) {
        // do whatever with your data object, it starts with QQ
        var myObj = localStorage[dataObj];
    }
}​
```

You could also change the if statement to this:

```
if(dataObj.substr(0,2) == "QQ") { // do your thing
```

Don't have a reference to the `substr()` documentation right now though, don't recall if that's the correct syntax.

Comment: thanks for your response. Having varmyObj will capture only the last record, not all the records. How do I capture all of the records?

Comment: It's a for loop, meaning it goes through all the records one at a time. During each iteration of the loop, `myObj` will hold the current record. If that doesn't make sense, you should read up on for loops.

Comment: -that makes sense. Have a question I see that my data looks like the following:  {"ID":68,"City":New York}

how do I get the value of City? I tried doing 

 var myObj = localStorage[dataObj];
 alert(myObj.City);

but that did not work. It shows undefined

Comment: I would use `if (dataObj.indexOf("QQ") === 0) { ` or `if (dataObj.match(/^QQ/)) {` instead, but this works.

Comment: Ah, @Nate, you'll want to 'decode' your JSON data. Do `var myObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[dataObj]);`, which will return an actual object instead of the JSON data. Also Nate, use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` and make your development life 100% happier.

Comment: @Jamund, very elegant solutions. I'm something of a JS beginner, I'm afraid, so I don't know those kind of techniques yet. I just went with what I knew worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can store an array in your localStorage.

Something **like** that (i haven't managed the Jsonify. you could use [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/saving/) to facilitate theses operations)

```
window.localStorage.setItem('QQ', {items: [] });

function addItem(id, json) {
  var o = window.localStorage.getItem('QQ');
  o.items[id] = json;
  window.localStorage.setItem(o);
}

function getItem(id) {
  return window.localStorage.getItem('QQ').items[id];
}

function getAllItems() {
   return window.localStorage.getItem('QQ').items;
}

function printAllItems() {
   var all = getAllItems();
   for (id in all) {
     console.log(id +" => "+ all[id]);
   }
}
```

Comment: For the getAllItems(), how do I specifiy getting all items that start with QQ? Thaks

Comment: All items that are "QQ-related" are stored in an array on the 'QQ' item in localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with databases, not storage (which is for key-value pairs). Try googling IndexedDB or Web SQL as keywords.

Comment: I definitely need to use the local db as I would be offline and local db will store info

Comment: @NatePet don't be misled by his answer. `localStorage` isn't perfect, but definitely can work in these scenarios when there is a small amount of data. IndexedDB and WebSQL both also work offline, but they're not nearly as well supported as `localStorage`, yet. They are built for bigger/better data storage though. http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/ http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

Answer (score 0):

Many frameworks like Sencha Touch and [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html) have some basic ability simulate DB functionality using `localStorage`. If you're excited to roll your own solution I would suggest doing something more like this:

```
// get the user store
var users = getUsers();
var john = user["john1234"];

// get all of the existing users
function getUsers() {
  return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.users) || {};
}

// save users
function saveUsers(users) {
  window.localStorage.users = JSON.stringify(users);
}

// add a user
function addUser(user) {
  var id = user.id || new Date().getTime();
  users[id] = user;
}
```

So my suggestion is instead of combining things based on a string separate them into separate collections or stores using standard

This is by no means a specific answer to your question but it might help you out!